# batch download from URL

Tags: linux, perl

I want to download thousand of files from a URL. Each line in "FileName.txt" contains the name of file to download. I am using a Perl script to take the file name from "FileName.txt" and downloading them after a random time. I run script as  "./program.pl Filename.txt"

Filename.txt

```
A
B
C
B
```

program.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file1=$ARGV[0];
open(FP1, $file1);
while($s1=<FP1>)
<br>
{   chomp ($s1);
    $range = 5;
    $minimum = 3;

    $random_number = int(rand($range)) + $minimum;
    `wget --wait="$random_number" "http://URL=$s1"`;
}
```

I am getting the output for few initial file but not for remaining file. For remaining file $ emacs fileD.txt give

```
[13] 29699
```

Could you kindly tell me why I am getting "[13] 29699", and what is the best way to download file after random time interval. Sorry, the program at while does not show the correct handler. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show where `$id` comes from, but presumably some URLs contain `&` which puts the process in the background. You should use single quotes for `wget`'s argument or use the list form of [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Further, wget's wait parameter is only relevant if your are using wget itself to traverse links from a given URL. In your case, you need your Perl script to sleep between invoking wget for each URL:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant WAIT_MINIMUM => 3;
use constant WAIT_RANGE => 5;

my ($url_list_file) = @ARGV;
defined($url_list_file)
    or die "Need URL list\n";

open my $fh, '<', $url_list_file
    or die "Cannot open '$url_list_file': $!";

while (my $url = <$fh>) {
    $url =~ s/\R\z//;
    my @cmd =  (wget => 'http://$url');

    print "@cmd\n";
    my $error = system @cmd;

    if ($error) {
        warn "''@cmd' failed: $?";
    }
    sleep WAIT_MINIMUM + rand(WAIT_RANGE);
}
```

Comment: Or use `LWP::Simple` in combination with a simple `sleep`

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the $id to $s1. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What means `URL=`? `wget` takes url as simple paramter. Seems to be you need

```
`wget --wait=$random_number 'http://$s1'`;
```